# '[...] upon which this invitation was based on' - is there an adverb redundant?

Tags: adverbs, clauses, subordinate-clauses

The whole sentence goes: 'Below is the list of criteria upon which this invitation was based on.'

It seems to me the adverbs 'upon' and 'on' are doubled up in this sentence. And it should be changed to either: '[...] upon which this invitation was based.'
Or: '[...] which this invitation was based on.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It should be one of the following two:

[1] a. *Below is the list of criteria [**(up)on** which this invitation was based].*
      b. *Below is the list of criteria [which this invitation was based **(up)on**].*

In both [1a] and [1b], the bracketed words are an **integrated relative clause**. Its non-relativized counterpart would be *this invitation was based on the list of criteria*. The relativized element is *the list of criteria*, and it enters as the complement of the preposition *(up)on*. In the relative construction, the preposition can be either **fronted**, as in [1a], or **stranded**, as in [1b] ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 1069).

Comment: Mark Liberman wrote in a Language Log post in March 2017 that he was "more than half convinced that [the use of both a fronted preposition and a stranded one] is not a slip of the tongue or pen, but rather a genuine syntactic innovation" ("[A stick with which to beat other women with](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=31432)").

Comment: @sumelic That's super interesting!